# mb_convert_encoding() with UTF-16 input in PHP > 8.1

Tags: php, utf-8, utf-16, octal, mb-convert-encoding

I'm updating a PHP app which imports CSV encoded in UTF-16 (from Google Keyword Planner) and the values are converted to UTF-8.

Until PHP 8 it's working as expected, but from PHP 8.1 there is a `?` added to the values after the conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8:

```php
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding("\0008\0008\0000\000", "UTF-8", "UTF-16"));

// Output with PHP 8.1.3 - 8.1.13, 8.2.0:
// string(4) "880?"

// Output with PHP 7.4.32, 8.0.8 - 8.0.26:
// string(3) "880"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source equals to `"\x00\x38\x00\x38\x00\x30\x00"`, which is 7 bytes and as such an [invalid length for UTF-16, which always needs 2 or 4 bytes per character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description).

- You're lucky enough PHP7 did silently accept the first 6 bytes and drop the 7th,
- while PHP8 now produces a more correct output as per UTF-16 LE and wants to tell you that there is an imcomplete 4th character, because there's only 1 byte for it.

Solution: provide proper input. Maybe it's also because you misunderstood the [octal notation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and would see it much better without mixing notation and literals altogether:

| approach | only 6 bytes (value `'880'`) | make it 8 bytes (value `'8800'` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| full hexadecimal notation | `"\x00\x38\x00\x38\x00\x30"` | `"\x00\x38\x00\x38\x00\x30\x00\x30"` |
| mixed hexadecimal notation | `"\x008\x008\x000"` | `"\x008\x008\x000\x000"` |
| full octal notation | `"\000\070\000\070\000\060"` | `"\000\070\000\070\000\060\000\060"` |
| mixed octal notation | `"\0008\0008\0000"` | `"\0008\0008\0000\0000"` |
| concatenated string to make it more clear | `"\x00". '8'. "\x00". '8'. "\x00". '0'` | `"\x00". '8'. "\x00". '8'. "\x00". '0'. "\x00". '0'` |

Comment: Correct, it seems parsing the UTF-16 LE encoded CSV on OSX native php install works as expected but in my Docker setup the encoding is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid PHP, simply use MySQL and its `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  Be sure to set the `character set` to utf16 or utf16le, depending on the "endian-ness".